# Is it possible to use "Add unimplemented methods" programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

After generating a class over an interface, I need a method has same function with Eclipse's "add unimplemented methods" function. I searched it but I cant find anything. Is there any way to use is like plug-in extension point or something else?

Thanks,
Zinon

---

Actually I create a project that creates a project using templates and information from user. It generates source code from templates in runtime. I have an interface class and some implementer classes that implement the interface class in template project.

```
public interface newInterface {
//Some methods here
String processStrings();
}


public newClass1 implements newInterface { 
String processStrings() {
 //processes here
}

public newClass2 implements newInterface { 
String processStrings() {
  //processes here
}
```

}

}

When I need to add a new method to the interface, I need to update the classes which implements the interface. Adding Unimplemented methods is just my idea for this problem but I'm not sure it is the ideal solution. Now is the problem clear?

Comment: what platform you're using?. ..If it's eclipse. .this is not a problem. :)

Comment: yes I use eclipse. I found source code of "AddUnimplementedMethodsOperation" class but can't afford exact usage.

Comment: @zinon - the source code is free ... why can't you afford to use it?

Comment: Stephen is right.. .If it's open source, why not use it?. :)

Comment: Of course it is open source, I'm not concerned about using it. I think i need an example to understand it's usage. :)

Comment: I do not understand why you need the same function as implemented. Where would you like to use it? Inside eclipse, the function is just defined, and outside, you are lacking the whole environment to  use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And I'll add to @mliebelt comment above that you have an option to create 'inheritade abstract methods' in the new class wizard.

In any case, and if you insist, take a look at the wizard's implementation, or at the UnimplementedCodeFix class implementation.

Also, the JDT tests for that feature are at the [AddUnimplementedMethodsTest](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ww3QUu6eohI/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/tests/core/source/AddUnimplementedMethodsTest.java&ct=rc&cd=1&q=jdt%20%22new%20AddUnimplementedMethodsOperation%22) class (line 365). The tests can also provide you with better understanding on how things work. However, note that you are dealing with internal JDT classes.

Comment: thanks finally found the usage, but you are right using internal class can be a bit trouble. I've updated the problem in the first post. Do you have any better idea to solve this problem

Comment: Not off the top of my head unfortunately.
I would investigate if JDT adds any `IHandler` implementation that can be executed through the handler service. If so, it will be encapsulated.
However, there is still the issue of the class/compilation-unit AST, and I'm not so sure if that's encapsulated.